# WordPress database error: [Table 'bitnami_wordpress.questions' doesn't exist]

Tags: plugin-development, database

I have wordpress installed via bitnami and i try to make a select request for questions (a table in my DB)

However it gave this error

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'bitnami_wordpress.questions' doesn't exist]
```

I tried everything... i renanmed my DB to bitnami_wordpress and also changed the DB name in the wp-config.php doing so however will crash Wordpress

Comment: have you confirmed with an SQL client such as PHPMyAdmin or Sequel Pro that the table does exist? Where does the questions table come from? WP doesn't have a questions table

Comment: Is another tables work ? If yes then clearly 'questions' table is not exists on your database.

Comment: Yes its on PHP Myadmin the questions table comes from that table